# Change JSON.net content via property name?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this structure :

```
  List<dynamic> lst = new List<dynamic>();
  lst.Add(new{objId = 1,myOtherColumn = 5});
  lst.Add(new{objId = 2,myOtherColumn = 6});
  lst.Add(new{lala = "asd" ,lala2 = 7});
```

I'm serializing it via :

```
 string st= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
```

**Question:**

How can I cause the serializer to change only *values* of the "`objId`" property , to something else ?

I know I should use `class Myconverter : JsonConverter` , but I didn't find any example which keeps the default behavior  and in addition - allow me to add condition logic of serialization.

Comment: Looking quite tricky.  As you say, you want to be using a custom `JsonConverter`, but since you're using anonymous types, the `CanConvert` method in the converter can't easily say "yes, I can handle that type".

Comment: @JamesThorpe if it helps , I didnt want to complicate things so I put this simple code , but in reality , the DATA can be anything : http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0M06.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a converter that will handle it, at least for simple objects as per your example.  It looks for objects containing `objId` properties and then serialises all properties it finds on them.  You may need to expand it to deal with other member types/more complex properties as required:

```
class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var prop in value.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            writer.WritePropertyName(prop.Name);
            if (prop.Name == "objId") {
                //modify objId values for example
                writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToInt32(prop.GetValue(value, null)) + 10); 
            } else {
                writer.WriteValue(prop.GetValue(value, null));
            }                
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        //only attempt to handle types that have an objId property
        return (objectType.GetProperties().Count(p => p.Name == "objId") == 1);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a converter that specifies it will only convert `int` types, then query where in the JSON path you are before doing any conversions.  This has the benefit of not needing to deal with all the other members of the anonymous type.

```
class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (writer.Path.EndsWith(".objId")) {
            writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToInt32(value) + 10);
        }
        else {
            writer.WriteValue(value);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (int);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```